# NServiceBus WinForm pub/subrror

Tags: winforms, nservicebus

ErrorInfo:
Cannot publish on this endpoint - no subscription storage has been configured. Add either 'MsmqSubscriptionStorage()' or 'DbSubscriptionStorage()' after 'NServiceBus.Configure.With()'.

Which friend can help me to provide the data or example
Thank you very much

Comment: The Error gives you two possible solutions. Did you try them out?